# What does 'Show ENDOOM Screen' mean?

Tags: mods, doom

I recently got [ChexQuest III](http://www.moddb.com/games/chex-quest/downloads/chex-quest-3-official-release) and was customizing the mouse sensitivity and video options when I saw a rather cryptic option: 'Show ENDOOM Screen'. It was set to OFF and I set it to ON just to see what it would do, but I couldn't notice anything different.

Is there anybody who knows what this means? I think it might have something to do with the graphics that come up after you complete an episode, but they weren't any different with  it ON or OFF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ENDOOM screen is actually a screen that shows up when you exit the game, however some ports do not have this screen, so that's the reasoning for having the option.

You can see some of the different ENDOOM screens at the [Doom Wiki](http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/ENDOOM).